# Consulta MySQL en varias tablas

Tags: mysql, sql

buenos días.

Estoy registrando la venta de un producto con SU ID único y precio, estoy queriendo hacer un reporte que me indique a que categoría pertenece ese producto que se encuentra en otra tabla.

Como puedo realizar la consulta en varias tablas ?

Comment: Bienvenido. Esto se suele hacer con `JOIN`. Aquí y en la red hay varios ejemplos que explican cómo hacerlo. Investiga, haz un intento y si te falla entonces plantea la pregunta basándote en el fallo concreto que estás teniendo. Esta es la forma en que funciona este sitio: se requiere que el interesado muestre un mínimo esfuerzo de lo que ha hecho. Gracias. [Aquí tienes un buen tutorial para empezar](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/). Está en inglés, pero se entiende muy bien. [Aquí otro](https://www.vichaunter.org/desarrollo-web/joins-mysql-bien-explicado-lo-necesitas-saber)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Deberías usar un `INNER JOIN`, su funcionalidad es "unir" las diferentes tablas con un "campo".

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT producto.id, producto.nombre, producto.precio, categoria.nombre 
FROM producto 
INNER JOIN categoria 
ON producto.categoria_id = categoria.id
```

En el caso de que la tabla `producto` contenga el `id` de la categoría al que pertenece (que es lo normal)

Comment: Perfecto, ya mismo lo pruebo.

Comment: @GustavoLopez Te sirvió la consulta?